# Making git case-insensitive to source code?

Tags: git

I would like to make git be case-insensitive to source code. Is there anyway to achieve this? (No, I don't want it to ignore case change in filepath.)

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve? Do you want to ignore case in filenames, or inside source code, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Well, sure, there is. If you want to hang yourself, git will gladly provide you <strike>enough rope</strike><sup>2</sup> a hook.<sup>1</sup>

Git itself tracks content and does not care about what the content is. Lower and uppercase letters are encoded as different bytes and that's all git knows.

However git is very extensible. You can tell it to use custom filter when reading files from disk, when writing them to disk, when calculating differences between them and when merging them.

If you want to make it case-preserving and just ignore case in `diff` and `merge`, you need to implement custom diff and merge drivers. Look up `diff` in [gitattributes(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). If you want to normalize everything to upper or lowercase, you need to implement read and write filters (called "clean" and "smudge"). Look up `filter` in [gitattributes(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). And than you have to apply it to appropriate files using the gitattributes mechanism.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, I really think it's a bad idea. Most programming languages are case-sensitive and for the ones that are not it would be much easier to just stick to one case (usually lower) yourself. But maybe under some circumstances it might be the best of bad options.

<sup>2</sup> You have to provide the rope (the filters to do the case conversion) yourself.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I have an older VB project and every once in a while a certain library will change case (e.g., DAO. winds up as dao.).  Doesn't bother anything code-wise, but it throws just about every module out of whack in git and it's a PITA to go back and change in the source just to avoid a merge conflict.  That said, not sure this filter is any better really, but at least it's an option I can weigh out.

Answer (score -1):

Git isn't case insensitive to source code, because source code isn't case insenstive. Changing the case of your code changes the meaning of the code. `var abc` and `var ABC` are two different variable declarations.

What you should do is to follow a proper coding style which adopts a case pattern to follow, and stick to it.

Comment: Actually, git isn't case insensitive, because lowercase and uppercase letters are encoded as different bytes. Because git does not care about source code. It does not even care about letters. It only knows about bytes!

Comment: *"`var abc` and `var ABC` are two different variable declarations"*. Not necessarily, there are some case insensitive languages. Most of them are older languages btw.

Comment: The programming language that I is case insensitive. (VB6)

Comment: @JanHudec yes, Git doesn't care about source code in particular. I should have framed my answer differently. It doesn't care what you have about written, so it won't even look for same letters in different cases.

Comment: @Abhi2011  even if that is the case, I would still stick to a proper standard of writing variables, if I have to use one of these older languages like VB6.

Comment: I would stick to using all my variables in a single case. But for some weird reason the case most of the times for single letter variables changes. (i becomes I)

Comment: @Abhi2011 wow, that's pretty messy. I guess the workaround would be to use caps for single letter variable names, as ugly as it sounds.

Comment: @Munim I think the standard is to have single variables in the lowercase. (All single variables are for loops.)

Comment: @Abhi2011 yes, that is obvious and well known. but if your IDE auto capitalizes them, do you really have a choice? I am still pretty shocked that variable names aren't case sensitive in VB6.